# unexpected code completion when typing div.row

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use bootstrap, and when typing html  I want emmet completion for div.row to be:

```
<div class= "row">
<div>
```

What I get is:

display:.row;

Here are my settings, trying to stop non emmet expansion. What can I do to get the expansion I want?

```
"html.suggest.angular1": false,
"html.suggest.ionic": false,
"html.suggest.html5": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
```

Comment: Hi did you get the the problem resolved?, I started using vscode, I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in settings json for one project. When i fixed the error emmit is working now.